# Do children hold the copyright over their own creative works?

Tags: united-states, minor

I was recently looking at a story I wrote when I was 8 years old. I presume that, however the law works exactly, I now hold copyright over it at age 30. But think about when I originally wrote it. Did I get automatic copyright ownership of it, as is typically the case when one makes a creative work? Or did my legal guardians hold the copyright instead, because I was a minor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Children own their own stuff

Legal guardians are legally responsible to preserve it and use it in the child’s best interest.

If doesn’t matter if that stuff is real, personal or intellectual property.